# How does CVXPY + CPLEX solve Lp-regression?

Tags: regression, cplex, cvxpy

I am using CVXPY with CPLEX as solver to solve a very simple Lp-regression problem.
The Python script I'm using is the following:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
import sys

m = 4
n = 2
p = float(sys.argv[1])

A = np.ones((m, n))
b = np.arange(m)
x = cp.Variable(n)
cost = cp.pnorm(A @ x - b, p)
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cost))
prob.solve(solver='CPLEX', verbose=True, cplex_filename='model.lp')
```

If I look at the `model.lp` for p = 1, I see that CPLEX is solving a standard Linear Programming model, as I expected:

```
\ENCODING=ISO-8859-1
\Problem name:

Minimize
 obj1: x1 + x2 + x3 + x4
Subject To
 c1: - x1 + x5 + x6 <= 0
 c2: - x2 + x5 + x6 <= 1
 c3: - x3 + x5 + x6 <= 2
 c4: - x4 + x5 + x6 <= 3
 c5: - x1 - x5 - x6 <= 0
 c6: - x2 - x5 - x6 <= -1
 c7: - x3 - x5 - x6 <= -2
 c8: - x4 - x5 - x6 <= -3
Bounds
      x1 Free
      x2 Free
      x3 Free
      x4 Free
      x5 Free
      x6 Free
End
```

Also, for p = 2 I obtain a very simple model, I guess because the resulting problem is a standard *least-squares* problem:

```
\ENCODING=ISO-8859-1
\Problem name:

Minimize
 obj1: x_0
Subject To
 c1: - x_0 + soc_t_0  = 0
 c2: - x_1 - x_2 + soc_x_1  = 0
 c3: - x_1 - x_2 + soc_x_2  = -1
 c4: - x_1 - x_2 + soc_x_3  = -2
 c5: - x_1 - x_2 + soc_x_4  = -3
 q1: [ - soc_t_0 ^2 + soc_x_1 ^2 + soc_x_2 ^2 + soc_x_3 ^2 + soc_x_4 ^2 ] <= 0
Bounds
      x_0 Free
      x_1 Free
      x_2 Free
      soc_x_1 Free
      soc_x_2 Free
      soc_x_3 Free
      soc_x_4 Free
End
```

On the other hand, if I start to plug-in other values for p, I get significantly larger and more complex models that I don't quite understand. Also, I observed that the number of constraints in the resulting model depends on the value of p. This is the one for p = 3:

```
\ENCODING=ISO-8859-1
\Problem name:

Minimize
 obj1: x_0
Subject To
 c1:  - x_0 + x_7 + x_8 + x_9 + x_10  = 0
 c2:  x_1 + x_2 - x_3 <= 0
 c3:  x_1 + x_2 - x_4 <= 1
 c4:  x_1 + x_2 - x_5 <= 2
 c5:  x_1 + x_2 - x_6 <= 3
 c6:  - x_1 - x_2 - x_3 <= 0
 c7:  - x_1 - x_2 - x_4 <= -1
 c8:  - x_1 - x_2 - x_5 <= -2
 c9:  - x_1 - x_2 - x_6 <= -3
 c10: - x_0 - x_11 + soc_t_9  = 0
 c11: - x_0 + x_11 + soc_x_10  = 0
 c12: - 2 x_3 + soc_x_11  = 0
 c13: - x_0 - x_12 + soc_t_12  = 0
 c14: - x_0 + x_12 + soc_x_13  = 0
 c15: - 2 x_4 + soc_x_14  = 0
 c16: - x_0 - x_13 + soc_t_15  = 0
 c17: - x_0 + x_13 + soc_x_16  = 0
 c18: - 2 x_5 + soc_x_17  = 0
 c19: - x_0 - x_14 + soc_t_18  = 0
 c20: - x_0 + x_14 + soc_x_19  = 0
 c21: - 2 x_6 + soc_x_20  = 0
 c22: - x_3 - x_7 + soc_t_21  = 0
 c23: x_3 - x_7 + soc_x_22  = 0
 c24: - 2 x_11 + soc_x_23  = 0
 c25: - x_4 - x_8 + soc_t_24  = 0
 c26: x_4 - x_8 + soc_x_25  = 0
 c27: - 2 x_12 + soc_x_26  = 0
 c28: - x_5 - x_9 + soc_t_27  = 0
 c29: x_5 - x_9 + soc_x_28  = 0
 c30: - 2 x_13 + soc_x_29  = 0
 c31: - x_6 - x_10 + soc_t_30  = 0
 c32: x_6 - x_10 + soc_x_31  = 0
 c33: - 2 x_14 + soc_x_32  = 0
 q1: [ - soc_t_9 ^2 + soc_x_10 ^2 + soc_x_11 ^2 ] <= 0
 q2: [ - soc_t_12 ^2 + soc_x_13 ^2 + soc_x_14 ^2 ] <= 0
 q3: [ - soc_t_15 ^2 + soc_x_16 ^2 + soc_x_17 ^2 ] <= 0
 q4: [ - soc_t_18 ^2 + soc_x_19 ^2 + soc_x_20 ^2 ] <= 0
 q5: [ - soc_t_21 ^2 + soc_x_22 ^2 + soc_x_23 ^2 ] <= 0
 q6: [ - soc_t_24 ^2 + soc_x_25 ^2 + soc_x_26 ^2 ] <= 0
 q7: [ - soc_t_27 ^2 + soc_x_28 ^2 + soc_x_29 ^2 ] <= 0
 q8: [ - soc_t_30 ^2 + soc_x_31 ^2 + soc_x_32 ^2 ] <= 0
Bounds
      x_0 Free
      x_1 Free
      x_2 Free
      x_3 Free
      x_4 Free
      x_5 Free
      x_6 Free
      x_7 Free
      x_8 Free
      x_9 Free
      x_10 Free
      x_11 Free
      x_12 Free
      x_13 Free
      x_14 Free
      soc_x_10 Free
      soc_x_11 Free
      soc_x_13 Free
      soc_x_14 Free
      soc_x_16 Free
      soc_x_17 Free
      soc_x_19 Free
      soc_x_20 Free
      soc_x_22 Free
      soc_x_23 Free
      soc_x_25 Free
      soc_x_26 Free
      soc_x_28 Free
      soc_x_29 Free
      soc_x_31 Free
      soc_x_32 Free
End
```

I guess this is because general Lp-regression problems can't be solved with the same techniques that can be used for p = 1, p = 2, or even p = infinity (as explained in the book "Convex Optimization").

Any idea of which technique is being applied here by CPLEX to obtain these models?

Comment: (Imho) this is a pure cvxpy-generated *conic reduction*. cplex did nothing but write it out. In regards to the how, i *[guess](https://ajfriendcvxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/functions/pnorm.html)* they follow `Farid Alizadeh and Donald Goldfarb. Second-order cone programming. Mathematical programming, 95(1):3–51, 2003. - 2.3. g) Inequalities involving p-norms`.

Comment: Every rational power ofa variable can be represented using a combination of quadratic cones, but sometimes it may be quite long . Here is a simplest possible example of 3/2: https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#simple-sets-involving-power-functions CVXPY must perform such a decomposition in order to express the problem in a form accepted by a SOCP solver. Some solvers can work directly with a general power cone.

Comment: @sascha it seems you are right, the technique used by CVXPY is the one described in that paper. Maybe you can answer to my question and I will accept it.